# TextView over a ImageView width

Tags: android, textview, imageview

This is a TextView over an ImageView.

http://myweb.midco.net/hgs/josey.png
(wont let me post image with 7 rep)

I have set the width and padding as such

```
 jTV.setWidth(1200);
 jTV.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
```

The ImageView is also set at a width of 1200 and the TextView is a movable text.  As I move it around I log the jTV.getWidth() and jIV.getWidth() and they both show 1200.  Why is the TextView less wide then the ImageView.  The answer will help me properly limit wher the text can be moved.  Thank you.

Comment: Any other margin padding?

Comment: There could be other padding I don't understand that is set by default. How can I set margin padding to 0?

Answer (score 0):

The actual `TextView` is in full width as the `ImageView`. The problem is that the text size is not as big as the `ImageView`. Try setting `layout_width` and `layout_height` to `wrap_content` and then play with the `layout_marginTop`, `layout_marginBottom` properties to "move" it around.

If you just want the text to be bigger just change the `textSize` property to your needs.